# Memory allocation in OS

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

Having this simple code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Empty{};

int main() {
    array<unique_ptr<Empty>, 1024> empties;

    for(size_t i =0; i < 1024; i++){
        empties[i] = make_unique<Empty>();
    }

    for(auto& element : empties){
        cout << "ptr: " << element.get() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

when running in ideone.com or Windows we get following result:

```
ptr: 0x2b601f0c9ca0
ptr: 0x2b601f0c9cc0
ptr: 0x2b601f0c9ce0
ptr: 0x2b601f0c9d00
ptr: 0x2b601f0c9d20
ptr: 0x2b601f0c9d40
ptr: 0x2b601f0c9d60 ...
```

For me it's totally strange. what kind of allocation algorithms in OS or standard library might cause, that there happened no allocation at address, that ends with number different than 0?

The reason I did this experiment is, that given the OS uses buddy algorithm, that manages pages and allocation request will cause OS to allocate a piece of contiguous memory, then a couple of next allocations (until running out of allocated memory) should be allocated quite nearby. If that would be the case , then probably cache issue with lists would not be so significant in some cases , but I got results I was not expecting anyways.

Also second number from the right in allocated nodes is totally randomly. What may cause such a behavior?

Comment: I don't know what OS you are using, but at least Linux aligns all heap allocations to 16 byte. Some tricky people like the llvm team actually use this fact to store stuff at those always zero bits.

Comment: The OS itself has nothing to do with this. The OS allocates pages, your program's allocator (likely from the standard lib you dynamically linked to, which might ship with the OS, but is not the OS itself) subdivides the pages into allocated blocks. It may need some space for the tracking info, align allocations for efficiency/fragmentation related reasons, etc. Having an empty allocation cost 32 bytes is not unreasonable/unheard of.

Comment: Even if the structure is empty it still need to have a size to be addressable. Added to that size will be the system allocators alignment and padding.

Comment: The difference between consecutive pointer values is 32 (bytes). That's not "totally random". Looks normal and as expected to me.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker For me expected would be 8 bytes, as it is smalles addressable unit

Comment: The second number from the right is **not** totally random. On the contrary, it's completely deterministic, and easy to predict: each address is 32 bytes higher than the previous one. 32 in hex is 20. In hex, if you start from ca0 and repeatedly add 20 you get exactly cc0, ce0, d00 and so on.

Comment: @FabioTurati true I did not notice that.

Comment: read @ShadowRanger's comment - you seem to be forgetting about the heap management overhead (and possibly alignment requirements).

Comment: @ShadowRanger this is why I ,,said allocation algorithms in OS or standard library'' (here meaning standard library implementation). Can you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: if you need 1 byte allocation then it is up to you to write an effective memory manager for this specific task.

Comment: Because it needs some space for housekeeping. Each memory block it takes should be self-describing, i.e. store at least its own length. Otherwise the standard library won't know how to delete it. So the amount of memory allocated is always more than the program asks. In addition, implementations often avoid allocating too small chunks for performance reasons, i.e. there's some minimum block size.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker sure they did, and I encouraged them to turn comments into answers, so that I can at least give them Up vote. n.m.s answer is totally not constructive and moreover a little bit offensing, as treating problem as obvious instead of explaining it is considered so.

Comment: @KonstantinL Hope, that you will have to implement something from scratch, next time, when you will have doubt or lack of knowledge about something.

Comment: I'm sorry if I have offended you in any way but my question is genuine. I really don't see how this sequence of addresses can provoke any doubt or suspicion.

Comment: No offence taken then :) my apologies for calling you bighead.

Answer (score -1):

The minimum size of a class in C++ is one byte, if I recall correctly. As there is a consistent 32 byte spacing between the class, it could be that that happens to be the sizeof the empty class you made. To determine this, try adding

```
std::cout << "Empty class size: " << sizeof(Empty) << std::endl;
```

It probably won't be 32 bytes, instead, there will probably be some consistent spacing between each object.

Note:
Does this compile for you. It doesn't for me because empties cant be implicitly initialised.

Comment: yes it does :) http://ideone.com/9lWs7Z. There should be no problem with initialization as unique_ptr has default constructor.

Comment: Hmmm. That is strange. Using clang with --std=c++14, so IDK then.

Comment: Please refer to given link in above comment for hint :)

Answer (score -2):

Please notice that the printed pointers is inaccurate, the OS allow you to see them as subsequent pointers when they could be allocated to an entirely different pages.

Comment: Why would they be allocated to different pages?

Comment: what OS are you talking about here ?

Comment: Windows OS, but I guess same would happen on Linux

Comment: @DawidPi I was actually asking user2733996 :)

Comment: Are you referring to virtual vs physical addresses? Physical addresses are of no interest whatsoever.

Comment: A typical approach to manage memory by OS is to allocate all the memory at the system initialization and allowing programs to rent them from the OS.
Now imagine if you don't have 1024 bytes available next to each other in the memory (you're low on memory for example) but you do have two chunks of 700 bytes.
The OS would allocate the first chunk of 700 bytes to the program and point the last byte to the next chunk, where it would allocate the first 324 bytes to it but still allow the program to view them as serialized.
See XINU management system or DOS.
Principle still applies today.

Comment: 1.  Operating systems typically allocate physical memory in pages.  These are typically 4k bytes these days (and 512 bytes on Vax).  The operating system cannot allocate less than a page.  2.  Describing a virtual address as "inaccurate" is completely misleading.  It may not be a physical address, but that is of ZERO interest to the OP.